# how to put a UIElement in a visual tree twice in different locations?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, visual-tree

i'd like to put a webbrowser twice in a grid twice in a wp app, but i got the exception:Element is already the child of another element. how can i solve this problem?
PS: i need two webbrowsers show at the same time, but i only need interact with one of them every time.

Comment: create a second instance of the control you wanna add

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add the same visual in two places, but you can create a visual brush from your "original" visual and display that elsewhere. You can have many "read-only" views into the WebBrowser, but only one interactive one.

Otherwise, you'll need 2 controls, each of which would be independent.

Comment: thx, could you give me some links on how to create a visual brush or make "read-only" views into the webbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

Create a second WebBrowser control.

A single control cannot be added twice as the error says.